# What does it mean by "foundered over financial terms and demands" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Could you please read the paragraph (incomplete) and tell me your answer?

This is an excerpt from an article on *The Economist* "[Why does Tata Group want Air India back?](https://www.economist.com/business/2021/10/16/why-does-tata-group-want-air-india-back)"—

"In recent years it was losing nearly $3m a day. Operating costs far exceed the industry average. So do customer complaints. Perhaps realising this, the government began trying to offload Air India in 2001, **but deals repeatedly foundered over financial terms and demands that the state retain a residual stake, and possibly residual control.**"

And my question is: what does the word "deals", and phrases "foundering over" and "financial terms" mean here? Also, could you please tell me what part does "demands" play in this sentence?

Comment: What does "founder" (as a verb) mean?

Comment: Perhaps it means "(of a plan, etc. ) to fail because of a particular problem or difficulty" as I found in oxford advanced learner's English-Chinese dictionary?

Comment: That is correct. I suggest you use the same dictionary for other words you do not know. Hints: In this case, “deals”and “demands” are nouns.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry, I have looked up all the words and phrases I don't understand, but I can't understand the whole sentence even with all these definitions. Sad:(

Answer (score 3):

A ship at sea *founders* when it sinks or hits the shore badly, particularly coming aground against rocks that break the hull of the ship. The word is being used in your case in a similar way. The deals, agreements, that are proposed *founder* that is fail or break apart on the harsh realities, the financial terms or conditions, of the state's demands, that is their requirement of a residual stake or control.

But agreements repeatedly fail because of financial requirements and demands that the state retain a residual stake, and possibly residual control."

Merriam Webster: *Founder*
intransitive verb
1 : to become disabled especially : to go lame
2 : to give way : collapse
3 : to become submerged : sink

Comment: A ship 'founders' when it sinks, in any circumstances or location, whether near the shore or hundreds of miles out to sea.

Comment: @Michael Harvey; Corrected, before I go down for the last time.